# Unique names within a one to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, relational-database, entity-framework-core

I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` (2.1.0) in a web api core (netcoreapp2.1) project in order to write `Blog` and `Article` entries to a (SQLite) database. They have a one to many relationship which I am implementing in the fluent api like this.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasIndex(b => b.Name).IsUnique();
  modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(b => b.Articles).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

And this is what the class definitions for `Blog` and `Article` look like:

```
public class Blog
{
    [Required]
    public Guid BlogId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String    Name { get; set; }
    public String    Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

}

public class Article
{
    [Required]
    public Guid      ArticleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Guid      BlogId   { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String    Name { get; set; }
    public String    Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime  Created { get; set; }
    public String    Content { get; set; }

}
```

The next requirement for `Article` is to have a unique `Name` within a ("parent") `Blog`. So I cannot just set it like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Article>().HasIndex(a => a.Name).IsUnique();
```

The above snippet would require each article to have a unique `Name` throughout the entire database. What I want is it to have a unique `Name` regarding the ("parent") `Blog` entry.

One solution that came to my mind was to explicitly check this condition before writing a new `Article` entry:

```
[HttpPost("{id}/articles")] // id - is the `Blog` id here
public IActionResult CreateArticle(Guid id, Article article)
{
  List<Article> articles = blogRepository.GetArticlesByBlogId(id);

  // Look up the names of all articles belonging to the affected `Blog`
  if (articles.Any(a => a.Name == article.Name))
  {
    return BadRequest("Article name is not unique!");
  }

  article.ArticleId = new Guid();
  article.BlogId = id;
  article.Created = DateTime.Now;

  blogRepository.AddArticle(article);
  blogRepository.SaveChanges();
  return CreatedAtRoute("GetArticle", new { id = article.ArticleId }, article);
}
```

I find this implementation not really elegant and I am also pretty sure that there has to be another way to do it. Can this be done using fluent api? What would be another approach than mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For combining `BlogId` and `Name` restrict, you could define a `Index` for `Article` like below:

```
        builder.Entity<Blog>().HasIndex(b => b.Name).IsUnique();
        builder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(b => b.Articles).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        builder.Entity<Article>().HasIndex(a => new { a.Name, a.BlogId }).IsUnique();
```